# Convert list of strings into list of floats when [float(i) for i in lst] does not work

Tags: python, arrays, list, type-conversion

I have a simple dataset of string numbers that I want to convert into floats. For some reason, the following works:

```
dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
array2 = [float(array[0])]
print(array2)
```

But if I do the following:

```
dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
array2 = [float(i) for i in array]
print(array2)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-d3f4342981c6> in <module>()
      1 dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
      2 array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
----> 3 array2 = [float(i) for i in array]
      4 print(array2)

<ipython-input-158-d3f4342981c6> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
      2 array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
----> 3 array2 = [float(i) for i in array]
      4 print(array2)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If I try:

```
dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
array2 = [float(array[i]) for i in array]
print(array2)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-60a5ed9c866f> in <module>()
      1 dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
      2 array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
----> 3 array2 = [float(array[i]) for i in array]
      4 print(array2)

<ipython-input-160-60a5ed9c866f> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
      2 array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
----> 3 array2 = [float(array[i]) for i in array]
      4 print(array2)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

And finally, if I try to go through map(), I can create:

```
dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
array2 = map(float, array)
print(array2)
```

But that only returns a location in Python 3; if I try to make it into a list like this:

```
dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
array2 = list(map(float, array))
print(array2)
```

I get an error again:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-68394d0c25fd> in <module>()
      1 dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
      2 array = dataset.read().split(", \n")
----> 3 array2 = list(map(float, array))
      4 print(array2)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I've also tried to append the values to a new list in a     for loop but to no avail. I'm fairly new to Python and this is frankly confusing... How come float() seems to work for one iteration of my data but not for the whole set?

Please note that the float() method works for any point of the array and printing the array gives me a "clean" list of strings, here's an excerpt:

```
['0.60237078', '0.404667', '0.081656125', '0.99716862', '0.70149429', '0.59545983', '0.97768306', '0.86360343', '0.57052565', '0.47777524', '0.040106169', ...]
```

Comment: What is the value of `array`, just before the list comprehension? The result of `split` probably had a string of whitespace as one of its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some error handling code:

```
dataset = open("data1.5.txt", "r")
array = dataset.read().split(", \n")

def float_report_errors(val):
    try:
        return float(val)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("float(", repr(val), ") -->", repr(e))

array2 = [float_report_errors(i) for i in array]
print("Indices with errors:", *(i for i,v in enumerate(array2) if v is None))
```

Chances are there are one or more non-float values hidden somewhere in your initial string array that are messing things up, but because you have a lot of values you're missing one somewhere.

Comment: Hi Amber, thank you for the quick answer. I've tried your code and I get the following:

'' --> ValueError('could not convert string to float: ',)
Indices with errors: 1000

Checking my array, the last value (the 1000th) is indeed only a space. Could this be throwing the whole thing out of balance?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening. Probably because the end of the file looks like `, \n` and so the split creates an empty string at the end. Try calling `.strip()` before splitting: `dataset.read().strip().split(", \n")`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I've added a basic del after creating the list and now it's all good. Marking this one as correct answer, and thank you for your time :)